# change edittext background with click

Tags: android-studio, android-edittext

I have 2 edittext in my app.
I want to change background when click on edittext.
this is my edit text:

```html
   <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:id="@+id/etUsername"
            android:text="  "/>
```

i want when click change this background.
I use the OnClick method 
this is working but I shoud have 2 click on edittext for change 
pleas help me
thanks...!

Comment: It is possible to configure a click counter?

Comment: I dont know !!! but how ??

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
etUsername .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) { 
      etUsername.setBackground(R.drawable.my_background);
        }
    });
```